# Change Bibtex citation for an arXiv paper

Tags: bibtex, citing, arxiv

(This is more arXiv related than LaTeX-related, so if there's a better place to put the question let me know.)
I was wondering if it's possible to change the bibtex citation that arXiv automatically generates for a paper I uploaded? (e.g. it's not capitalizing words that need to be capitalized, it's not adding a URL, etc.) Can I somehow change this when I log into the arXiv account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to TeX, so this issue will be closed programmatically...

The "export bibtex citation" will take whatever is entered into the metadata (unless you've entered a DOI manually, in which case it will take whatever CrossRef says the title is). Please [contact arXiv help](https://arxiv.org/help/contact) directly to resolve this issue with your paper.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your response!